# Android multiple actions for one Button

Tags: android, android-activity, camera

Good Day guys! I am really serioulsy stuck on programming my android application.This is the problem guys.
I have application which uses camera broadcasting with surface View.I got only one button which by idea should make access to a camera then after accessing it take a picture.
I tried if and else statements but didn't help me.I searched whole internet nobody can give any good solution.
So by idea that only one button in one activity should do these two functions:Open camera,after opening capture.
Please help me and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like a simple enough problem. One of the solutions would be to use 2 listeners and just switch between them:

```
Button button;

final Button.OnClickListener listener2 = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Take picture
    }
};
Button.OnClickListener listener1 = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Open camera
        v.setOnClickListener(listener2);
    }
};

button.setOnClickListener(listener1);

// Later at some point, e.g. when camera is closed:
button.setOnClickListener(listener1);
```

Comment: OH thanks very much,hope it will help,because neither if and else statement helped nor arranging the list of button actions,hope this one will help,but i got a question,why you setting again a listener after method ends?

Comment: And why setting on listener one as well?

Comment: @VladimirArevshatyan because when the camera is opened, you want that button to perform another action, thus you set a new listener. *Note:* the setOnClickListener is to be run somewhere later in your code, it's just an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use boolean to keep track of camera state(open or close). Then depending upon the boolean value you can call two different methods. Like : mCameraOpen is boolean

```
`@Override
public void onClick(View v){
  if (mCameraOpen){
     methodToCaptureImage();
  }else{
     mCameraOpen = true;
     methodToOpenCamera();
  }
}`
```

Comment: Hmmm very interesting solution ill try this too though

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't need 2 listeners. You don't even need one! Just use android:onClick property in the layout to bind a function to the button press like this: `android:onClick="onButtonPress"`. Then use the camera itself to determine the button's action. Just have the camera object null when it is not active. Here's the Java code:

```
Camera mCamera = null;
Button mButton;

private void openCamera(){
    try{
        mCamera = Camera.open();
        mButton.setText(<your text here>);
    } catch (RuntimeException ex){
        // Handle exception if cannot access camera
    }
}

private void releaseCamera(){
    mCamera.release();
    mCamera = null;
    mButton.setText(<your text here>);
}

private void captureImage(){
    // Whatever you do to capture image
}

public void onButtonPress(View clickedView){
    if (mCamera == null) openCamera();
    else captureImage();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks but as i mentioned im BROADCASTING camera not gettin access mainly and straight to native camera so i need to start camera activity from my own activity